# How to output test pass/failure notification to slack through Jenkins when running pabot

Tags: jenkins, robotframework, slack

I want to set up notifications in slack through Jenkins using pabot(parallel run of robot framework tests).

I have already configured Jenkins to output the pass/failure/skip notifications when using robot, but once I change it to pabot the notification no long appears in my slack channel.

This command runs successfully and my slack channel is notified of the tests 
 that pass/fail/skip

`robot -A Config/Config.args -d results -v REMOTE_URL:http://dummy:0000/wd/hub Tests`
[image]

On the other hand this command alerts my channel that the build has commenced but nothing after that

`pabot -A Config/Config.args -d results -v REMOTE_URL:http://dummy:0000/wd/hub Tests`

[image: successful configuration]
In the directory the a pabot_results file is created which is different to the build with the robot command. But the output.xml, log.html and report.html files include the expected results.

I want the basic pass/fail/skip to appear in the slack channel for parallel run test. At the minute no test results are appearing in the slack channel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Jenkins declarative pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) and I have solved problem following way in post section after running robot tests using [Token Macro plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/token-macro/):

```
post {
    always {
        robot(
            outputPath: 'Reports/',
            outputFileName: 'output.xml',
            reportFileName: 'report.html',
            logFileName: 'log.html',
            disableArchiveOutput: false,
            passThreshold: 100.0,
            unstableThreshold: 95.0,
            otherFiles: '*.png,debug.log'
        )
        script {
            String robotReportSummary = tm('ROBOT_FAILEDCASES: ${ROBOT_FAILEDCASES}, ROBOT_PASSPERCENTAGE: ${ROBOT_PASSPERCENTAGE}, ROBOT_PASSRATIO: ${ROBOT_PASSRATIO}, ROBOT_REPORTLINK: ${ROBOT_REPORTLINK}')
            // Instead of echo step you can use whatever you want with variable robotReportSummary
            echo "${robotReportSummary}"
        }
    }
}
```

Further info:

From documentation of [Robot Framework plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/robot/) is visible plugin exports following token macros:

- `${ROBOT_FAILEDCASES}`
- `${ROBOT_PASSPERCENTAGE, onlyCritical}`
- `${ROBOT_PASSRATIO, onlyCritical}`
- `${ROBOT_REPORTLINK}`

As well from [source code of Robot Framework plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/robot-plugin) it can be found other undocumented token macros:

- `${ROBOT_FAILED}`
- `${ROBOT_PASSED}`
- `${ROBOT_TOTAL}`

In order to access these macros in declarative pipeline you can use [Token Macro plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/token-macro/) and it's pipeline step [tm](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/token-macro/). From documentation it's not clear that it returns string with replaced variables. But usage can be found e.g. [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/token-macro-plugin/blob/main/src/test/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/tokenmacro/impl/BuildStatusMacroTest.java#L46) in source code of Token Macro plugin.